# .htaccess subdomain rewrite/redirect with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

i have a problem with my site.

How can i redirect all subdomains with exceptions?

**My Problem:** I want to rewrite all subdomains (*) to the main domain (Example: `http://*.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`), but my question is how can i add an exception?

**What i want:** `mySpecialDomain.example.com` and `myOtherSpecialDomain.example.com` should be the same as before.

thanks for all answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mySpecialDomain|myOtherSpecialDomain)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```